# Windows 10: How to assign Outlook as default handler for .ics files

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, file-types

Apparently due to some recent Windows 10 update the default application to handle .ics (calendar) files is suddenly set to the Windows 10 Calendar app. Since I never use that crappy app I wanted to assign this back to Outlook, which I am using as my day-to-day PIM.
But when I try to assign the default back to Outlook the default application dialog only displays the options "Calendar" and "Search the store for an application". There used to be a link "choose another application" here, that would allow to assign the file type to any locally installed application, but that link is gone! :-O

So, how to I re-assign this .ics filetype to Outlook???

Comment: Same problem here.....it is amazing how Microsoft can screw things up that have been working for over a decade.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that I never added the solution I had found - so adding this now:

Editing the registry key did the trick:

```
Key:
Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-....\Software\Classes\ics_auto_file\shell\open\command
Value:
REGSZ: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Outlook.exe" /ical "%1"
```

The number in ...\Office16\... may vary depending on the version of your installed Office-version.

Answer (score -1):

Windows Key -> then type "File Associations"

Or

"Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Associations"

You can then select from a list of all known file types, and assign applications to use them.

Comment: Nope! That's my point. There used to be an option "Look for another app on this PC" but in this case it is missing!
 I can only choose that dreaded Calendar app or "Look for an app in the store", neither of which fits my bill.

Comment: @mmo Can you edit your question to include a screenshot of your version of the window in the following image - https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Windows-10-My-Capture-0003.png.pagespeed.ce.YSwdzLbY3f.png